# Firefox Add-on Builder extension debugging

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

Hello I am using Firefox Add-on Builder for Firefox extensions. I am trying some basic code examples from their page, but I have a problem with logging simple text.

Firebug doesn't work as I read through Google, people recommended Firefox error console, but it gives me an errors instead of "text" from console.log.

Please check this image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uM3YR.png

I really need to somehow see what console.log returns for debugging purposes, otherwise I cannot make my extension :(

Answer (score 1):

`console.log` only works using the Add-on SDK.  There are various logging levels, but only `console.error('message goes here')` will show up in the regular browser error console screen that you have shown.